# How to retrieve the highest voted candidate name with number of votes from table

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

This is my php code of webpage. I want to retrieve the candidate's name as well as number of votes. But I don't know how to. As you can see I have tried a lot but no use. My database name is election, my table name is votes. In table I have 3 columns id, name, votes, and only three candidate are inserted (not more than that).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RESULT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/WTL/js/validateLogin.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.btn{

    border-radius:15px;
    border:solid 2px #B22222;
    padding:5px;
    width:10%;
    height:8%;
    background-color:white;
    float:center;

}

</style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
<img src="http://localhost/WTL/images/home2.jpg" id="home" width="1350" height="180">
</div>
<div name="header2">
<form name="result" method="post" action="">
<Table class="tabb" align="center" >
<th>
<font size="5px" color="#B22222">RESULT</font>
</th>

   <tr><td><input type="textarea" rows="6" cols="50" width="50%" height="50%" name="resultDisplay" placeholder="click result to check the result" class="textarea"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <center><div name="header3" class="last"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="RESULT" onclick="validate();" class="btn" ></div></center>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
session_start();
$display= "";

if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
{
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election");
if($db->connect_error)
{
    die("connection failed".$db->connect_error);

}   
else
{
    $sql="SELECT name,votes FROM cr
        WHERE votes = (SELECT Max(votes) FROM cr)";
    $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    //$name=$res['name'];
    //$votes=$res['votes'];
    echo '<textarea>', $res , '</textarea>';
    //$display .= '<div>'.$name.' '.$votes.'</div>';
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: *"help! its urgent"* - Oh I see. Btw, you can't use "echo" that `$res` query.

Comment: yup i know but i m trying cause i have no idea what to do

Comment: Why don't you just order descending by votes with limit 1? `SELECT name,votes FROM cr ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 1` - a bit clearer.

Comment: and how to display the result.? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: you need to "loop" over successful results. You can't just `echo $res` like that. You need either a `while` or `foreach`. It's all in the manual on this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and there are many tutorials on the web.

Comment: you're also more than likely outputting before header with the position of `session_start();` - That should be above output and error reporting would have triggered a headers sent warning http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - if you're not assigning any session arrays then you can safely remove it.

Comment: `<input type="textarea"` that's invalid also. Your code contains too many errors. Where's this JS function also `validate()`?

Comment: Your `table`-markup is also invalid (`<th>` without `<tr>`) and `float: center;` is invalid too.

Comment: got output $sql="SELECT name,votes FROM cr
        WHERE votes = (SELECT Max(votes) FROM cr)";
 $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {

         echo '<textarea>'. $row['name'] .'</textarea><br/>';
         echo '<textarea>'. $row['votes'] .'</textarea><br/>';
    }

Comment: Even though I like scaisEdge and he's a good code, I honestly cannot see why the answer was accepted, given the too many errors outlined by myself in comments. Should my comments disappear, the answer will not let people know what they are/were.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The original question contain  many mistakes which mostly seems to have segnalated  by the comments to the question and other answers this response is limited to only part of the code which relates to the display of results

for get the result you should  use a loop (assuming that you have not errors) for access to each row array and proper index for get the each  column

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {

         echo '<textarea>'. $row['name'] .'</textarea><br/>';
         echo '<textarea>'. $row['votes'] .'</textarea><br/>';
    }
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson   .. correct  .. (i prefer dot concatenation)

Comment: There are quite a few other errors in their code, as I stated in comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  not only  a few .. seems  a lot .. i have suggested only the main problem .. (by me)

Comment: Just way too many. IMHO, the question contains too many errors and a few unknowns.

Comment: Have a look at all (my) comments under their question ;-)

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge worked!!! thanks!!

Comment: @Fred-ii-   . I saw your comments as always are right  and well documented, ... since it seems a new user .. I thought I would give an example of code .. I think may be useful to the user

Comment: It seems that all the suggestions have worked

Comment: @scaisEdge IMHO, the answer is incomplete; it doesn't fully cover all the errors, even though I have in comments (and did not want to post an answer for many reasons). If my comments happen to vanish (which is entirely possible), then future readers to the question probably won't know the real (full) solution. The solution should not be based on comments.

Comment: @scaisEdge what if my comments vanish? *lol!!* anyway... I think that was a bad question. I like you and all, but given the amount of rep and experience you have, you should have put all that in your answer, rather than relying on comments.

Comment: @scaisEdge I delete comments from time to time (I can, they're mine *lol*). I'm not asking you to delete the answer since it does solve the "immediate" problem; looping over (successful) results. However, you have to think about future readers to the question. Some of them may even be (low rep) members who think they can post partial answers. In doing so, would only be sending out the wrong message. I think you can agree with me on that.

Comment: @scaisEdge Sure, if you want to pull all my comments from up there ;-) Many a times I delete comments because they're often ignored by the OP and I just move on.

Comment: @scaisEdge I came back to see how this was doing. Not my downvote here buddy; sorry to see you got those :(

Comment: @Fred-ii   I know you're a good guy .. do not worry .. but someone does not like my answer .. so .. I do not like to have answers with negative votes, although I believe that new users should also be helped with answers like this

Comment: @scaisEdge It's "one of those" (questions) unfortunately :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- Where I come from they say that no expert is born .. a person can best course .. but if then is helped learns .. if you get punished no .. one only gets bad .. why when I meet a person does not try to help her espderta .. regardless of the fact that I have 10 points or 30,000 .. and that demand is more or less done well   ... anyway .. thanks for the moral support is always welcome.

Comment: @scaisEdge You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score -3):

You have an error in your sql syntax. Your code should be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RESULT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/WTL/js/validateLogin.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.btn{

    border-radius:15px;
    border:solid 2px #B22222;
    padding:5px;
    width:10%;
    height:8%;
    background-color:white;
    float:center;

}

</style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
<img src="http://localhost/WTL/images/home2.jpg" id="home" width="1350" height="180">
</div>
<div name="header2">
<form name="result" method="post" action="">
<Table class="tabb" align="center" >
<th>
<font size="5px" color="#B22222">RESULT</font>
</th>

   <tr><td><input type="textarea" rows="6" cols="50" width="50%" height="50%" name="resultDisplay" placeholder="click result to check the result" class="textarea"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <center><div name="header3" class="last"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="RESULT" onclick="validate();" class="btn" ></div></center>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$display= "";

if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
{
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election");
if($db->connect_error)
{
    die("connection failed".$db->connect_error);

}   
else
{
    $sql="SELECT name, Max(votes) as vote FROM cr group by name";
    $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    //$name=$res['name'];
    //$votes=$res['votes'];
    echo '<textarea>'.$res['name'].' - '.$res['vote'].'</textarea>';
    //$display .= '<div>'.$name.' '.$votes.'</div>';
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: it says Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in blah blah ...

Comment: His SQL wasn't the issue. You'r example wouldn't work since `mysqli_query()` doesn't return an array...

Comment: got output...$sql="SELECT name,votes FROM cr
        WHERE votes = (SELECT Max(votes) FROM cr)";
 $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {

         echo '<textarea>'. $row['name'] .'</textarea><br/>';
         echo '<textarea>'. $row['votes'] .'</textarea><br/>';
    }